# Use a reflected instance of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime, activator

I'm dealing with reflection stuffs, I've got a problem with a reflected instance of ObservableCollection. I mean, if create a new instance of it with:

```
Type virtualObservable = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
object observable = virtualObservable.MakeGenericType(genericType)
```

I've got an object, but I can't use it like a ObservableCollection, that is what I need.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. If `genericType` is known at compile time, cast the return value of `MakeGenericType` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` using that type of as the generic parameter.
2. If you are on .NET 4.0, make observable of type `dynamic`, not `object`.
3. Cast `observable` to the type you need, i.e. if you want to register for the `CollectionChanged` event, cast it to `INotifyCollectionChanged`. If you want to iterate over it, cast it to `IEnumerable`.

I think you can't use the first option, because if you could, the whole reflection approach would be unnecessary. The second approach leaves you with no IntelliSense support while developing. I think option 3 is the best one.

Sample for option 3:
If you want to add a new item to the collection, you need to cast it to `ICollection` and use the non-generic `Add` method:

```
ICollection tmp = (ICollection)observable;
tmp.Add(yourObject);
```

Comment: Yess, I don't want to know the type at compile-time. Dynamic seems very interesting, but I'm more interested in casting to interfaces. What if I want to add elements to a collection using the standard Add<T>() method?